# Ping a website and save the data in an .csv file

Tags: c#, .net, csv, ping

When the code is RUN it has to ping the websites I specify 4 times each and then write the results in a .csv file. But I'm keep getting a TIMEOUT error. Can anyone tell me why? I tried so many different things and noting is working so far. Please help me out.

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string> lstWebSites = new List<string>();
            lstWebSites.Add("www.yahoo.com");
            lstWebSites.Add("www.att.com");
            lstWebSites.Add("www.verizon");
            string filename = @"PingLog.csv";
            {
                using (var writer = new StreamWriter(filename, true)) 
                {
                    foreach(string website in lstWebSites)
                    {
                        writer.WriteLine(website);
                        try
                        {
                            Ping myPing = new Ping();
                            PingReply reply = myPing.Send(website, 1000);
                            if (reply != null)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", reply.Address, reply.RoundtripTime);
                            }
                        }                   
                        catch
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine.("ERROR: You have some TIMEOUT issue");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There are syntax errors in the above code. Are you using an IDE? You're missing quotes around your filename, and you're using a variable called `stream` without ever declaring it

Comment: You are not even using the `writer` you are just writing on the console and the initialization of your `SteamWriter` seems to be wrong. Also, as others have said please provide your errors.

Comment: The error now is that I have an ArgumentException Unhandled Error.

Comment: by the way I added in: using (var stream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))

Comment: @Zee: Please provide a [mcve]. It's really hard to help debug code that won't even compile in the first place. Edit your question to add the exact code you're running, and provide full stack traces when you capture the errors.

Comment: @Zee: please do not modify the question in a way that answers that were already given become invalid. I have rolled the changes back. If Cory's answer helped you solve some severe problems, then accept it. Ask a new question if there are still some issues remaining.

Comment: This code compiles, and sorry if it seems like I'm not thankful for your help, specially cory. I am very thankful, I appreciate you taking the time to help me figure this out its just that I'm trying to get this done as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I have most of this figured out. Thank you all so much for helping me. 
Although, I still need this to ping at least three more websites and give me 4 ping results per website. 
So if someone could please, please just help me out a little bit more.
Here is what I have and this so far it works:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Ping Application
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string filename = @"PingLog.csv";
            {
                using (var writer = new StreamWriter(filename, true)) 
                {
                    writer.WriteLine("www.yahoo.com", Time in MilliSeconds);
                    try
                    {
                        Ping myPing = new Ping();
                        PingReply reply = myPing.Send("www.yahoo.com", 1000);
                        if (reply != null)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}", reply.Address, reply.RoundtripTime, reply.RoundtripTime);
                        }
                    }                   
                    catch
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine.("ERROR: You have some TIMEOUT issue");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working example. I added some comments where you had syntax errors or where I made adjustments to your original code.

```
// Missing quotes, should probably be a full file path
string filename = @"C:\temp\PingLog.csv";

// You had an extra opening brace here

// Open a file for writing using the filename, and a flag that means whether to append
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(filename, false))
{
    // Write a CSV header
    writer.WriteLine("Status, Time, Address");
    try
    {
        Ping myPing = new Ping();
        PingReply reply = myPing.Send("www.yahoo.com", 1000);
        if (reply != null)
        {
            // Use the overload of WriteLine that accepts string format and arguments
            writer.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}", reply.Status, reply.RoundtripTime, reply.Address);
        }
    }
    catch
    {                   
        // You had a syntax error here
        Console.WriteLine("ERROR: You have some TIMEOUT issue");
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same error: DirectoryNotFoundException was Unhandled. And the false turns red. Also, Additional information- could not find a part of the path @"C:\temp\PingLog.csv";

Comment: What is the error? I ran this exact code without error before I posted it.

Comment: I'm still getting the same error: DirectoryNotFoundException was Unhandled. And the false turns red. Also, Additional information- could not find a part of the path @"C:\temp\PingLog.csv";

Comment: You should change the file path the match something on your filesystem. You can add additional code to check whether a directory exists and create it if it doesn't exist. I leave that as an exercise for you.